# Detecting click outside element doesn't recognise children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const outSideClick = (e) => {
      if (!filter?.current?.contains(e.target)) {
        setOpen(false)
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', outSideClick)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', outSideClick)
    }
  }, [])
```

It works for the most part but I have a specific filter item that has a select component that has its own options and when I click on those it doesn't recognise them as something within that element even though the place where I click is still inside the main parent container. I also tried with `onBlur` and `tabIndex` but it is even worse

Comment: You filter your components with a target value. This target value triggers the HTML element of the one you just clicked on. However, it's not possible to fire the parent div when you click on its children. I believe you need to reconsider your filtering strategy.